# How do we use 'Stockholm syndrome' in a sentence?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

How do we use '***Stockholm Syndrome***' in a sentence?

Can it be used for the things we hate?

Comment: No. It's a very specific psychological phenomenon associated with being held hostage, wherein hostages becomes empathetic with their abductors (see Patty Hearst). It is not used to depict hostage takers or other things you might hate.

Answer (score 1):

Watch Imtiaz Ali's *[Highway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_%282014_Hindi_film%29)*:

> The film outlines the story of a young woman who is kidnapped before her wedding and held for ransom wherein she develops **Stockholm syndrome** towards her kidnapper.

From the [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stockholm%20syndrome):

> 1-After many failed attempts to escape, the woman quit trying because she had developed **Stockholm Syndrome** for her captor.
>
> 2-Even though the toddler didn't like his new toy, he developed a **Stockholm Syndrome** for it. [emphasis added]